# Problem with mounting Sambashare

Tags: 20.04, samba, sharing, smb

When I try to mount my sambashare I get an error saying: no such file or directory, despite it's undisputed existence in my root directory.
I have tried to secure the share somewhat so only local users would have access.

The folder ownership lays with the samba group.
Testparm outputs the correct .conf location, as well as the message that the service files are ok. My Server Role is Standalone.

```
The service status is:
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-14 12:33:50 CEST; 11s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 15309 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 15355 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18984)
     Memory: 8.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
             ├─15355 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─15358 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─15359 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─15361 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Sep 14 12:33:49 gross systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Sep 14 12:33:50 gross smbd[15355]: [2020/09/14 12:33:50.010714,  0] ../../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(daemon_ready)
Sep 14 12:33:50 gross systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Sep 14 12:33:50 gross smbd[15355]:   daemon_ready: daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
```

My Config FIle looks as follows:

```
[global]
#workgroup = smb
workgroup = sambashare
security = user
#map to guest = never
usershare owner only = false
#usershare allow guests = Yes
#usershare max shares = 100
#usershare owner only = Yes
#usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares


#[homes]
#comment = Home Directories
#browseable = no
#valid users = %S
#writeable = yes
#create mode = 0600
#directory mode = 0700


#[public]
#path = /media/storage/ 
#public = yes
#writable = yes
#comment = smb share
#printable = no
#guest ok = no

[SECURED]
path = /samba/shares
valid users = @sambashare
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate it since I am fairly new to Linux.

Comment: Have you added your 'local' users as Samba users with 'smbpasswd -a <username>' and are they also members of the 'sambashare' group ?

Comment: Yes I did that also, I should have provided this information :D

Comment: They are listed and members of the appropriate group. I've also tried resetting the password of one of the users multiple times but to no avail...

Comment: Could you post the command you use for the mount?

Comment: i use the GUI of ubuntu. + other files, samba://mydomain.xz/sambasharepath

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks I found the answer :D I mixed up the path and the samba share name...
I tried to access vie smb://userdomain.xy/samba/shares  . When i tried it via smb://userdomain.xy/secured, it worked :D
Thanks for answering anyway.